# What is the best way to move JFrame to 2nd display in Windows 10

Tags: java, swing, windows-10

I'm trying to move my jframe to second display automatically in windows 10 but its not working, I'm using JDK8, and video drivers are upto date below is my code:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DualMonitor {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();

        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((java.awt.Component) null, "Found : " + gs.length, "screen detected ?",
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);

        for (int j = 0; j < gs.length; j++) {
            GraphicsDevice gd = gs[j];
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(gd.getDefaultConfiguration());
            frame.setTitle("I'm on monitor #" + j);
            frame.setSize(400, 200);
            frame.add(new JLabel("hello world"));
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setLocation`?

Comment: Okay, so having a bit of dig around I can confirm that it works under MacOS. I can also confirm that it's also using the `setLocationByPlatform` AFTER calling `setLocation` to place the window on the specified device, this "might" be having some affect on the placement of the windows, but I can't confirm it

Comment: issue is resolved by `setLocationRelativeTo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved by using `setLocationRelativeTo`, `setUndecorated` and `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` check below:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DualMonitor {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();

        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((java.awt.Component) null, "Found : " + gs.length, "screen detected ?",
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);

        for (int j = 0; j < gs.length; j++) {
            GraphicsDevice gd = gs[j];
            JFrame dualview = new JFrame(gd.getDefaultConfiguration());

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(dualview);
            dualview.dispose();

            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setTitle("I'm on monitor #" + j);
            frame.setSize(400, 200);
            frame.add(new JLabel("hello world"));
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't explain why `dualview` doesn't "seem" to work - since `setLocationRelativeTo` would suggest that `dualview` is actually on the screen screen. I'd consider trying `setLocationByPlatform(true)` first, but that's just me

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but I tried `setLocationByPlatform` and its not working for me, that's why I have tried above code and its working fine, but let me try your suggestion again on other pc, may be driver issue